# /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1 is not ready yet or not present - message on boot

Tags: system-installation

On boot I am getting the following message,

```
The Disk Drive for /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1 is not ready yet or not present.

Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for Manual Recovery
```

Help on what can I do?

Comment: What is your disk configuration? Do you have a single internal disk, or multiple ones? On what disk is elementary installed? Does your computer boot with UEFI?

Comment: Looks like your /etc/fstab is malformed or necessary partition is missing.
post us contents of the following commands:
# cat /etc/fstab
# lsblk
# pvs
# vgs
# lvs

Comment: Could you copy here you fstab file ?